# Azure Logic APPS share SMTP Connector in several logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have setup the SMTP connector (V3) in a group_shared
I have setup a logic app in resourcegroup group_A and a logic app in group_B.

[image]

Using visual studio code I want to setup some workflows in these resourcegroups (A and B) using the shared SMTP Mail function.I am always stuggeling with the setup in the connections.json.

I tried to add the API details into the connections.json and than adjust my workflow but it's not using the connection and want to create a new one.
[image]

[image]
What is the best way to use share API's?

Comment: I found a workaround by manipulating the local.settings.json,   "WORKFLOWS_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME": "group_shared". << default it contains the LogicApp resourcegroep.

Comment: It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue with a workaround. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.